# how do i get a form to remove part of a link before submit?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, submit

Say i had a form input to submit a facebook user id, but some don't read and submit the whole link how do i remove the part of the link i don't want, before form submit?

```
<form>
Facebook id: <input type="text" name="facebookid">
</form>
```

and the user enters this:

> www.facebook.com/UserProfleID

How do i get it to remove the "www.facebook.com/" and just leave the ID? before submit?

Thanks heaps for your time, any help would be great

Comment: Use Javascript. What have you tried? Simplest solution .. split by '/', get last element of the array.

Comment: on submit explode the link on / and only use the part you want

Comment: Why would you want to removed it before submit? You will have to check this on the server side anyway.

Comment: Don't. Instead, munge the data when it gets to the server. You have more control there.

Comment: If they haven't read the instructions correctly and enter the wrong thing, validate it server-side (in your PHP) and return an error telling them so.

Comment: i coded it to add the other part and there no going back now :) and to be honest i really just wanted to know... so  RegularExpressions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are the one receiving the form**, you can just play with the string before starting to work with it.
You could delete the substring you dont want using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('www.facebook.com/', '', $input);
str_replace('facebook.com/', '', $input);
str_replace('http://facebook.com', '', $input);
```

Although I would recommend you to use regular expressions with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

**If you have no control after the submission** of the form, then you can use Javascript and make use of the split function:

```
//str = input string
var parts = str.split("facebook.com/");

//alerting the username
alert(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, will try str_replace i don't want to bother the user anymore then necessary.. so the less they have to do the better :)

Comment: Any of the methods given require no work on the user's side. 
Regular expressions will give you the best result. 
For the 1st example, if the URL they put is https://facebook.com, you'll need to add that rule in too.

Comment: @JayHuang if you feel that way, why not mark a +1 to each of us who advised RegEx.  On a side note, I'm perplexed why this answer is the only one marked as the answer when his says what mine does, with the exception he used psuedo code and I used English =/

Comment: I'm simply addressing his concern of having users do more work. I'm also pretty sure only 1 answer can be selected on SO, hence the definition of "answer". Realistically though, the focus should be helping the OP find a solution that works; not worrying about whether or not you were selected as the best answer...

Comment: "Any of the methods given require no work on the user's side."  Anthony Grist method gives them a error, which waste their time... like i said i can't mark down?

Comment: @Steve I stand by my question to Jay, since your answer was simply the code version of the answer I'd given.  However, I concede your point that PHP is not pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept the form submit with javascript and let the user know they made an error. But as others have said you should still validate on the server.

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
     var input = document.getElementsByName('facebookid')[0].split("/");
     if(input.length > 1){ 
         //should do this part with fancy CSS and not an alert box
         alert("Enter your id only plix plox");
         return false;
      }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: No problemo. although it only checks for the presence of / I think it catches allot of the posible variations that are possible:https://,http://,facebook.com/,etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
Facebook id: <input type="text" id="userid" name="facebookid">
</form>



$("form").submit( function () {
var arr= $("#userid").val().split("facebook.com/");
$("#userid").val(arr[1]);
} );
```

It might help you.

Answer (score -1):

If you expect the prefix to be predictable, then you can use a dictionary of strings you can Remove from the input.

However, if you're not able to predict the input, then Regular expressions give you the flexibility to predict the pattern but not the value to be removed.

I would use RegularExpressions if this were my code...largely because I'm fan of writing the least code to do the most work.

Comment: if you're going to mark me down, at least explain your criticism since I'm correct.

Comment: Wasn't me who did, im under 15 rep so i couldn't if i wanted to? i'm guessing its because you didn't provide code? really i don't know...